# Jquery ajaxSubmit also does the regular form submit

Tags: ajax, magento, jquery, form-submit

I'm trying to run the following Jquery ajaxSubmit for one of my Magento stores. I use ajaxSubmit because I have 2 files to upload from the form as well (Means I need data in `$_FILE`). But when I do the ajaxSubmit it also dose the normal form submit which will refresh the page and take me to the next page, instead of staying on the same page where I have a pop-up box with some more stuff in it. I have ***`return false;`*** to prevent this, but it fails.
The submit code:

```
$('#quickbuyform').submit(function (){

    // No Accessories: normal submit
    if ($('#accessories ul li').size()==0) {
        return true;
    }

    strName = "<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>";

    // loading message
    $('#pop_accessories_area_message').html("We are adding '"+strName+"' into your shopping cart ...");
    // Pop with loading
    popAccessories();

    // loading icon
    //var dataString = $('#quickbuyform').serialize();
    $.ajaxSubmit({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: $('#quickbuyform').attr('action'),
          data: dataString,  
          beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
          success: function() {
            // display cart link:
            $('#pop_accessories_area_message').html(strName+" was added to <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'>your shopping cart</a>.");
            $('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();
            //window.location = '<?php //echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>';
          }  
        });
    return false;
});
```

So this is what I have now with `e.preventDefault()`, but now it does not Submit anything. Just stop at `('#quickbuyform').ajaxSubmit`

```
$('#quickbuyform').submit(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // No Accessories: normal submit
    if ($('#accessories ul li').size()==0) {
        return true;
    }

    strName = "<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>";

    // loading message
    $('#pop_accessories_area_message').html("We are adding '"+strName+"' into your shopping cart ...");
    // Pop with loading
    popAccessories();

    $('#quickbuyform').ajaxSubmit({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: $('#quickbuyform').attr('action'),
          data: dataString,  
          success: function() {
            // display cart link:
            $('#pop_accessories_area_message').html(strName+" was added to <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'>your shopping cart</a>.");
            $('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();
            //window.location = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>';
          }  
        });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the `url` option if the correct url is in the `action` attribute of the form, ajaxSubmit will use this by default.

Answer (score 3):

You can stop the normal form submit by calling `preventDefault` method of the event object.

```
$('#quickbuyform').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Comment: I tried e.preventDefault(); but it I out the statement at the top of the function it stop submitting the form, if I put just before the return false;, it does the normal submit. Any idea where to put this statement..??

Comment: You should add it at the top. The ajaxSubmit method should still submit the form as usual.

Comment: Yep, I had it at the top, but after that ajaxSubmit was not called , if I remove it, ajaxSubmit will call but as a normal submit :(

Comment: Are you suppose to write `$('#quickbuyform').ajaxSubmit()` instead of `$.ajaxSubmit()`?

Comment: Add an ) after the }, as in '$('#quickbuyform').submit(function (e) {e.preventDefault();})`

Answer (score 0):

Try using $.ajax instead, or `e.preventDefault();` as suggested above:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",  
          url: $('#quickbuyform').attr('action'),
          data: dataString,  
          beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
          success: function() {
            // display cart link:
            $('#pop_accessories_area_message').html(strName+" was added to <a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>'>your shopping cart</a>.");
            $('.pop_accessories_area_button').show();
            //window.location = '<?php //echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart') ?>';
          }  
});
```

Comment: $.ajax will not post files to $_FILE array... so $ajax is out I reckon

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this -

```
$("#quickbuyform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });​
```

This will prevent the default behavior of your jQuery event.